# Remove duplicates from a list of tuples containing floats

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of size 2 tuples which have floats in them. Some of the floats are nearly equal and are close enough to be considered equal. numpy isclose() can be used with good effect here. I need to remove the duplicates in the list while always retaining the first value.

```
import numpy as np
data=zip(C1,C2)
comparray=[]
eval1=np.isclose(data[0],data[1])
comparray.append(eval1[0])
i=0
while i<(len(data)-1):
    eval=np.isclose(data[i],data[i+1])
    print eval
    comparray.append(eval[0])        
    i+=1
l1=[a for a,b in zip(data,comparray) if not b]
```

I have this code which does what I need, but it seems really poor. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you give input and output examples?

Comment: In terms of doing something 'more pythonic' I think writing a function then using map is probably the way to go.

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: You should include some tuples and lists definitions as example to clearly show what you want. For example `data=[ (9.6,7.7), (6.7,6.8) ]` or things like that. I answered you question (correctly, I believe) but I can't be sure because I can't check against your data.

Comment: The input is in the form--> data=[(0.0,0.0),(0.679,64.7999999999829),(0.679,64.80000000000041),(1.2,69.00000004470348)] etc.....In this example, the output would be [(0.0,0.0),(1.2,69.00000004470348)]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can do

```
out=[ a for a,b in zip(data,data[1:]) if not np.isclose(a,b) ]
```

but I can't really test this, as you didn't provide any input/output examples.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the structure called a "Set"?

Sets are a collection of unordered unique elements. I believe this structure would save you a lot of overhead and be a much better fit based on your description.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: Thank you, yes I am familiar with sets, however they consider items that are very close as unique whereas I need to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `function` like this

```
def nearly_equal(a,b,sig_fig=2):
    return ( a==b or 
             int(a*10**sig_fig) == int(b*10**sig_fig)
           )

>>>print nearly_equal(3.456,3.457)
True
```